# How to dynamically set page titles in the browser tab in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a scenario like there's a list of employees in the developing application. When I click one employee name, it navigates to that employee's details. Whenever i navigate to each employee's details, my browser title should display information like **“Employee Name: Employee Number"**. So that the title should change according to the employee.

Suppose I am also having list of departments and there the same thing should happen; if i navigate to department component browser title should display information like **“Department Name: Department Number”**.

Please suggest how to achieve this in ***generic way*** instead of setting title in each component.

Answer (score 7):

Angular provides a TitleService that allows you to change the title of the page at any given time.

It is here:

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Either in a custom service, you can listen for route changes, fetch the bottom-most route and change the title based on the data passed on the router.

```
public title: string = '';

constructor(private router: Router,  
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,  
    private titleService: Title) {}  

ngOnInit() {  
    this.router.events.pipe(  
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),  
    ).subscribe(() =>
        this.titleService.setTitle(this.title));
}  

getChild(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {  
    if (activatedRoute.firstChild) {  
        return this.getChild(activatedRoute.firstChild);  
    } else {  
        return activatedRoute;  
    }
}
```

You can then set the title you want for each component.

```
constructor(private customService: CustomService) {
    this.customService.title = 'Whatever you want';
}
```

Comment: This does not fulfill the requirement. That is, I need the title of the same component dynamic.

Comment: Just create a service as I said, with a function to set a title field. Then in each component, you'll need to set the desired title and on NavigationEnd the service will update the browser's title. PS: edited my answer to fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the solution provided by Leonardo for the custom service will not work. The ngOnInit method will not be effective, whereas ngOnDestroy will be. To resolve this, you need to move the subscription to the constructor.

Comment: please format your answer

Comment: left a message for minor improvements

Comment: i lack of reputations to init a comment